# Post data from ajax request empty in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my javascript code :

```
            var json = JSON.stringify(data);

            $.ajax({
                data: {data : json },
                type: 'POST',
                url : 'test.php',
                success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert(data);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(jqXHR);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR);
                    alert(textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

Here is my test.php :

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

`success` function returns correctly the data

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  string(51) "["image_0","image_1","image_2","image_3","image_4"]"
}
```

But in my test.php `var_dump()` return an empty array..

```
array(0) { }
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);`??? Don't dump a string even shouldn't return empty array

Comment: This doesnt make sense - your js success function is displaying the data returned by the php script. You say this is working, but th php is not?? This cannot happen.

Comment: Well $_POST will be empty if you hit your test.php directly without posting any data to it. Thus if you goto test.php you get an empty array. But when you post to it via your javascript code, you are posting data to it, thus $_POST is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you simplify like

```
$.ajax({
  data: JSON.stringify(data)
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I understand my mistake. Sorry but I'am newbie in javascript.

In my test.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["data"])) {
    $_SESSION["test"] = $_POST["data"];
}
echo $_SESSION["test"];
```

Comment: So what was your mistake? If you post an answer, answer the question, even it is your own question (could be useful for futur readers...)